# Handling intense Swipetorefresh function in Android

Tags: android, android-volley, swiperefreshlayout

i want to know is there any way to know the state of swipetorefresh() function in android. what i mean is whenever i called swipetorefresh() to refresh a listView intensely (calling it when the function is still running over and over again) it executes it, despite that it is still running, thus make my app crash. when i log it the problem is index confusion in my adapter so if there is a way to know that the swipetorefresh() is still running i can reject the user calling method swipetorefresh() again and again.

Comment: you should debug your code and find out the problem causing index , it must due to arraylist size , debug it

Comment: You need to stop it from refreshing  e.g like you see here (setRefreshing(false);) but the code has it as the last thing it does. I assume you will want to do that 1st too just incase there is a refresh going https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/

Comment: Thinking about it why dont you use flags e.g (running = yes or no) so when you swipe to refresh set (running = yes) and when its done set (running = no). Then its a simple case of (if running = yes then do nothing else set running = yes and go and do the refresh) in your refresh function(code)  at the end after (setRefreshing(false);)  set running = no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Boolean to check if swipetorefresh is running or not

Just set boolean value true in onRefresh() method and set it false when you get response from your API call.

And when boolean is true disable swiperefresh.